# Windows as a virtual machine

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, kali-linux

I was wondering if there were any downsides to implementing windows 10 as a virtual machine on a Linux (Kali) host system. I have a G751JL Asus and have had a ton of trouble dual booting Kali Linux with windows I also tried Linux as a virtual machine and had the same trouble. Now my windows is kind of messed up with drivers not working right and powering off randomly. I have tried to figure it out using the event viewer with no luck. So I was wondering if I install Linux as my host then windows as my virtual machine if it would be bad.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can install Linux and then Windows 10 in a virtual machine, but remember that a virtual machine has basic hardware and there is a performance penalty compared to running Windows natively. That means that you get a typical graphics card without 3D acceleration or with very little 3D acceleration, so you cannot play demanding games in a virtual machine. Also the computer will not be as fast as running Windows 10 natively since it is running two operating systems in parallel and the RAM of the virtual will be a fraction of the available system RAM. Also not all virtual machines support USB devices, so if you want to use one (such as a printer) make sure you choose one that does support USB. I would prefer better performance in Windows for obvious reasons, so I would install Windows 10 natively (host OS) and then Linux in virtual (guest OS). The choice is yours.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since it is a gaming laptop I will stay with windows as the host and try to work all the bugs out of installing the Linux OS.